# Trying to find parts of sting inside cells VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So a little intro:
I have a workbook with about 15 or 16 sheets. This data is a log of the people who have stayed at my hotel, so each sheet, named after the name and year that the guest has stayed (i.e. Mar2017) and has 4 columns (Guest name, Check in date, Check out date, Room).
On a separate sheet, named "Dados" I have the reviews that each guest has given us. Now this Review data is insert through the user via an userform.

What I am trying to do:
Every review that the user introduces into the form, it looks the information of the guest in the month sheets.

I tried running a Vlookup but failed as my problem here is that the user sometimes only introduces the Surname of the guest and inside the cell with the guest name we would have something like "john Smith"

I look through google and found that this might be done with the "like" command however this is not finding matches. This is the code I compiled at the moment:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Data()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wn As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim shName As String
Dim cData As Variant
Dim sLastRow As Long, s As Long
Dim lLastRow As Long, j As Long
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dados")
Set wn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("List")


lLastRow = Cells(wn.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1

With ws
 LastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

 For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 2 To lLastRow
        shName = wn.Cells(j, 4).Value
        Set sh = Worksheets(shName)
        sLastRow = Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        For s = 2 To sLastRow
            If sh.Cells(s, 1) Like "*" & .Cells(i, 1) & "*" Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3)
            If IsDate(cData) = True Then Exit For
        Next s
        If IsDate(cData) = True Then Exit For
    Next j
 Next i
End With

End Sub
```

In the Sheet "List" I have the list of all my sheets which is generated through another sub. (I won't bother you with this code as it runs perfectly) this is so I can compare the guest name with all the sheets. the number goes in:

```
 lLastRow = Cells(wn.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

First of all I would like to apologize for the crudeness of my code, I've been learning to code vba on my own. And most of it comes from posts here and other websites.

I apreciate if any of you guys could help me to make this work. This:

```
If sh.Cells(s, 1) Like "*" & .Cells(i, 1) & "*" Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3)
```

Is not getting me anywhere on the matches.

Also the time that takes to process the code is huge as you can imagine, if you guys could give a simpler way to achieve this I would be most grateful (I have looked everywhere on the internet and nowhere can I find anything simpler)

Thanks in advance,
Pedro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Like` check is okay

but you have to explicitly and properly qualify the worksheet object you want to reference to

so:

```
lLastRow = Cells(wn.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

becomes:

```
lLastRow = wn.Cells(wn.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row + 1
```

and:

```
sLastRow = Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

becomes:

```
sLastRow = sh.Cells(sh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1
```

Comment: This helped me Solve it. Thank you. It was not the issue but part of it.  The main issue apparently was the definition of what to compare. However because of this solution I was able to get to the main solution: Define variables for the comparison, If sh.Cells(s, 1) Like "*" & .Cells(i, 1) & "*" Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3) became If sName Like "*" & cName & "*" Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use InStr function which finds a string within a string.
InStr(1, sh.Cells(s, 1), .Cells(i, 1), 1). This will return a numeric value.

```
If InStr(1, UCase(sh.Cells(s, 1), UCase(.Cells(i, 1)) <> 0 Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Instr along with LCase for string searching. LCase makes the search case insensitive.

`If InStr(1, LCase(sh.Cells(s, 1), LCase(.Cells(i, 1)) Then cData = sh.Cells(s, 3)`